# Facing issue while consuming or producing data to a topic on specific server VPC

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I m trying make producer using kafka and spring boot.

I have tried creating new application to produce message on a topic and to be consumed by other application. When m starting the server topic is not being recognized initially only. Error which is coming is shown below:

```
2021-09-03 15:33:20.024 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=lims-public-helper] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : { sms.requests=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
2021-09-03 15:33:20.026 WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=lims-public-helper] The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [ sms.requests]
```

I tried with other server it is working very fine with same configuration tried this server it is giving exception.

Kafka topics

```
$ kaf topics 
NAME PARTITIONS REPLICAS 
__consumer_offsets 50 3 
__trace 9 1 
sms.requests 3 1 
sms.status 1 3 
test 1 3
```

Consumer code:

```
 public ConsumerFactory<String, OtpDTO> otpConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, limsGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "otpDTO:com.lims.helper.dto.OtpDTO");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.lims.helper.dto.OtpDTO");
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(OtpDTO.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, OtpDTO> otpKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, OtpDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(otpConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

consumer listner details:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.lims.sms.otp}", containerFactory = "otpKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void otpTopicMessage(@Payload OtpDTO otpDTO) {
        log.info(String.format("--------#####  otp topic consumer: %s", otpDTO));
    }
```

properties details of topic:

```
spring.kafka.topic.lims.sms.otp=sms.requests
spring.kafka.topic.lims.sms.status=sms.status
```

Comment: 2021-09-03 15:33:20.024  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=lims-public-helper] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : { sms.requests=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
2021-09-03 15:33:20.026  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=lims-public-helper] The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [ sms.requests]

Comment: but in case topic not present on server it should create that topic rite because i have enabled it

Comment: Consumers never create topics if they do not exist

Comment: ok but what can be the reason of this error? 
Do you think some networking issue or ssl issue?

Comment: The connection appears to be established fine since you aren't getting a TLS error or network timeout.

Comment: yes initial connect is done perfectly fine but then why it is not recognizing topic even if it is present on server..

Comment: I dont know why you changed the logs, but it looks like you have a space in the topic name now... `{ sms.requests=` and `[ sms.requests]`. Can you show your actual consumer code as a [mcve]?

Comment: i did checked the code there is not space in properties file

Comment: consumer code added above.

Comment: added above in the question itself

Comment: Added in the question..

Comment: @OneCricketeer any suggestion ? 
did you find any mistake in the code?

Comment: What were you asking about tls? You have no properties related to that

Comment: yes i don't have i was just asking but as we can see initial connect is getting connected so i don't think that is an issue

Comment: Any other reason u think?